# Mac Mojave .bash_profile environment variables not picking up

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I am editing environment variables in macOS Mojave in this file:

```
/Users/newuser/.bash_profile
```

Added a line as follows

```
export nameframe="newname"
```

After that when I tried `echo $nameframe`, I'm getting nothing in return. What am I doing wrong? How can I add custom environment variables permanently that can stay even after reboot in macOS mojave?

Comment: have you restarted your terminal or ran `source ~/.bash_profile`?. Also, what do you see when you run `cat ~/.bash_profile | grep nameframe`?

Comment: wow, after running source it is showing up, thanks, what source command do?

Comment: great! by running `source ~/.bash_profile` you're simply injecting the updated `bash_profile` into your terminal. It's similar to restarting: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command

Answer (score 2):

Check if your shell is using Bash. Run the following command in your terminal: `echo $0`. If the output is `-bash` or `/bin/bash`, then your shell is using Bash. Otherwise, it's `zsh`.

If your shell is using `zsh`, then you need to add the environment variable to a different file. In `zsh`, the file you need to use is `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.